# Сортировка коллекции GameObject

Tags: c#, unity3d

Есть код, который ищет некоторые объекты по тегу.

```
public List<GameObject> Targets;

Targets = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Point").ToList();
```

Объекты кроме координат отличаются по имени (Point 1, Point 2 и т.д.)

После проведения этой операции имею коллекцию

Point 5, Point 4, Point 3.. - по убыванию. Хотя объекты создавались дубликатом по очереди.

В связи с этим пара вопросов:

1. Каким образом правильно отсортировать данную коллекцию
2. С чем связано такое заполнение коллекции.

Answer (score 0):

разобрался:

```
Targets = Targets.OrderBy(x => x.name).ToList();
```

До этого пытался отсортировать список, но не присваивал его никуда

Comment: У листа есть встроенная сортировка(через делегат или интерфейс)